# Wrap all controller actions in transactions in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

Is it possible to set up a Rails application such that all controller actions are automatically wrapped with a transaction, that gets automatically rolled back in case of unrescued exceptions?

I'm working on a Rails 3 application, currently for a fairly tricky action that makes numerous database changes.  And I've been getting it wrong, lots of times!  After a while I realised my code wasn't working because I'd ended up with inconsistent data in the database.

I can easily enough wrap this with a transaction (it is a clear instance where one is needed!).  However it got me thinking that, at least in development, it would be useful to apply this idea across every controller action.

Assuming it is possible, is there any downside to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can it be done? probably.
Should it be done? probably not, otherwise this would be part of rails, or there would already be a great gem for this.

If you have particular complex controller actions that are doing lots of db activity, and you want them to be in a transaction, my advice is to get this business logic and persistence into a model method, and put your transaction there.  This also gives you more control for the cases where you may not always want this to happen.

If you really, really want to do this anyway, I would bet you could do it with Rack middleware, like this (untested) one https://gist.github.com/1477287:

```
# make this class in lib/transactional_requests.rb, and load it on start
require 'activerecord'

class TransactionalRequests
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end

# and in the app config
config.middleware.use "TransactionalRequest"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to have a think about whether this is a good idea.  I guess the problem is that any transactions I use within the application will really just be bundled up into the outside transaction.  However, for some reason seeing that, it gave me the idea how to do it.  I'll post with my solution so the code is more easily readable!

Comment: Coming from Python/SQLAlchemy, coupling a transaction to the web request is standard practice and I was surprised that this is not done in Rails/Sinatra. Here is some background info from the SQLAlchemy docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications

Comment: It's in rails docs as an example https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters

Answer (score 19):

For info, I did this with an around_filter in my application controller:

```
around_filter :wrap_in_transaction

def wrap_in_transaction
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    yield
  end
end
```

This just rolls back the transaction on any unhandled exception, and re-raises the exception.

Comment: I like this idea but how do I get access to after_commit and after_rollback callbacks using this?

Comment: I strongly suggest to add a sleep rand before yield it again - this thing can explode your machine if you have many concurrent transactions.

Comment: @fotanus I am not sure I understand what you mean. How does adding a sleep fix the problem of many concurrent transactions?

Comment: @tsauerwein comment is from 2014, so I'm not sure. Answer could have been edited.